# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Unable to redirect different page than what it is supposed to be

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, httpresponse, http-redirect

In my program I am trying to make the server redirect the user to a different page if the wrong details of some sort are put in. The main problem that I am having is that whenever I try to use res.redirect() with another web page as a parameter I get the following error back: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

I am not sure if I am referencing the web page in terms of where its stored on my computer wrong but something else about http headers was mentioned.

Here is my code that might potentially help to show what is wrong:

```
app.post("/profile.html", (req, res)=>
{

    if(req.body.login_name == undefined)
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM connectfour.players WHERE username =" + "'" + req.body.signup_name + "';";
        connection.query(sql, function(error, results)
        {
            if(error) throw error;


            if(results.length > 0)
            {
                console.log(res);
                res.redirect("/start");
                var already_taken = "username " + req.body.signup_name + " is already taken";
                res.render("start", {already_taken});
            }
            else
            {
                var signup_name = req.signup_name;
                res.render("profile", {signup_name});
            }
        });
    }
```

So the form on another page posts the request for the profile.html page. Then something is checked to detect if the username is logging in or signing up. An SQL query happens with the data sent over. If the user already exists then the user will get sent over to a page that will make them try to signup again. This contains the `res.redirect` problem:

profile.ejs is what the page requested is supposed to be. But I need to redirect it to start.ejs if the if statement mentioning if(results.length > 0) happens. I would try to post an image showing what my problem is but the problem is that my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: you cannot send multiple responses you have to use either `res.render` or `res.redirect`

Comment: @aRvi That's where a problem comes. I have tried using ```res.render("start", {already_taken});``` on its own but this just redirected the user to the profile page still which should not happen in this case. When I just used ```res.redirect("/start");``` I get an error returned back saying that ```Cannot GET /start``` directly on the web-page

Comment: have you tried commenting it `res.redirect("/start");` AS there is no API with /start to handle that request

Comment: @aRvi What do you mean by commenting it (commenting it out?)

Comment: by removing that line of code or commenting it `// res.redirect("/start");`

Comment: @aRvi When I remove the line ```res.redirect``` and that would have to mean I would use ```res.render("start", {already_taken});``` (or else nothing would happen when the request comes through). This just directs the user to the ```profile.html``` page (which is what I am trying to aim to not happen and avoid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either call `res.redirect` or `res.render`. Both sets status and returns it and some info to a client. If '/start' is processed by some Express route handler (that renders using `res.render("start", {already_taken});`) when just redirect to it and that's all.

Comment: That's where a problem comes. I have tried using ```res.render("start", {already_taken});``` on its own but this just redirected the user to the profile page still which should not happen in this case. When I just used ```res.redirect("/start");``` I get an error returned back saying that ```Cannot GET /start``` directly on the web-page